# mongod command doesn't work : mongodb intallation on windows

Tags: windows, mongodb

i have installed mongoDB in windows but the mongod command doesn't work
i have checked all the steps the mongodb -version works well
but when i execute mongod command i get

```
*{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.357+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   
"ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify -- 
sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.362+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   
"ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.362+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, 
"ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.364+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, 
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr": 
{"pid":12116,"port":27017,"dbPath":"C:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-7ETJDI1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.364+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 
7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.364+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo": 
{"version":"4.4.0","gitVersion":"563487e100c4215e2dce98d0af2a6a5a2d67c5cf","modules": 
[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment": 
{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.364+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 
10","version":"10.0 (build 19041)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.364+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.366+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr": 
{"dbpath":"C:/data/db/","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.366+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr": 
{"config":"create,cache_size=3525M,session_max=33000,eviction= 
(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log= 
(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager= 
(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log= 
(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.571+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:570770] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.636+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:636233] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.705+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:705049] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery 
loop: starting at 4/9984 to 5/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.817+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:816269] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 4 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.910+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:910279] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 5 through 5"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:51.964+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1599296811:964138] 
[12116:140707954185456], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global 
recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.137+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, 
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":771}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.138+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp": 
{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.146+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.227+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22120,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Access control is not enabled for the database. Read and write access to 
data and configuration is unrestricted","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.229+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":22140,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"This server is bound to localhost. Remote systems will be unable to 
connect to this server. Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP addresses it 
should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is 
desired, start the server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning","tags": 
["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.250+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.565+02:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":23718,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to initialize Performance Counters for FTDC","attr":{"error": 
{"code":179,"codeName":"WindowsPdhError","errmsg":"PdhExpandCounterPathW failed with 'L’objet 
spécifié n’a pas été trouvé sur l’ordinateur.' for counter '\\Processor(_Total)\\% Idle Time'"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.565+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   
"ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr": 
{"dataDirectory":"C:/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.570+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   
"ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"127.0.0.1"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-09-05T11:06:52.570+02:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   
"ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}*
```

and it blocked there does anyone know where the problem might be

Comment: Start `mongo.exe` and connect to the database.

Answer (score 2):

It's working.

The message `"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}` means it has completed startup and is waiting for something to connect.

Comment: I didn't understand, what should I do to complete the connection

Comment: connect to 127.0.0.1:27017 with the mongo shell or one of the drivers.  `mongod` is the command to start a MongoDB server,  `mongo` is the command to use the mongo shell to connect to a server.